# Getting error while importing apache.commons.net file in jsp program

Tags: jsp, telnet, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-commons-net

Below Error i am getting while running jsp program
I am using Apache Tomcat server and manually i placed into my project under webapp and i was downloaded apache.common.net jar files and i have added those jar file into my classpath aslo but those are not importing .

```
An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /QISDB.jsp
TelnetClient cannot be resolved to a type
12: 
13: <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
14: <% 
15: TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
16: 
17: try {
18:   telnet.connect("google.com", 80);
```

This is my Jsp Program

```
<html>
<head><title>QISTest</title></head>
<body>
<table>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetNotificationHandler"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.SimpleOptionHandler" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.EchoOptionHandler" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TerminalTypeOptionHandler" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.SuppressGAOptionHandler" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.net.telnet.InvalidTelnetOptionException" %>

<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<% 
TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

try {
  telnet.connect("google.com", 80);
  System.out.println("connection succesful");
} catch(IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Exception while reading socket:" + e.getMessage());
} finally {
  telnet.disconnect();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you put `commons-net.jar`?

Comment: Yes ,added to classpath

Comment: Do you put it to the WEB-INF/lib Folder?

Comment: Yes ,I tried both ways